# On Mac, is it possible to create two shared lib that depends on each other?

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

On Linux
I can create two coupled shared library `lib1` `lib2`. Since linking happens on a latter stage, so it is fine.

But on Mac, dylib are "linked". which means that creating `lib1` would requires `lib2` to exists first, which then requires `lib1` to exists first, which is impossible.

Is my understanding right? Is it really impossible?

I would need to reorganize my project if it is really impossible.

Comment: I think this is impossible, and so it is on Windows. I am a bit surprised that it is possible on Linux. Anyway, having cross-dependencies between libraries is always a bad idea.

Comment: @parpin it's actually just for development, so cmake won't recreate the whole binary every time something changed